# Backbone event shows cached model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new on backbone and using backbone with requirejs to make my first SPA. 
When a user navigates to site.com/#report/1 an API call goes to site.com/app/report/1 and collects the data and renders the data in view page. Then, he goes to dashboard and navigates to site.com/#report/2 and another API call collects data of report 2 and displays as well. The problem is when I am using any event handler. In the view page, when anyone clicks on any event, in the callback it says that there is two JSON object saved as model. But it should be the second one only. The first report data also comes in console.log.

For your better understanding, I am giving the code of my router, model and view page.

**Router**

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'models/authlogin',
], function (Backbone, AuthloginModel) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            '': 'renderLoginPage',
            'dashboard': 'renderDashBoard',
            'report/:id': 'renderReportDetails',
            'report/new': 'renderNewReportPage',
            'members': 'renderMembersPage',
            'member/:id': 'renderMemberPage',
            'login': 'renderLoginPage',
            'organization': 'renderOrganizationPage',
            'programs': 'renderProgramsPage',
            'program/:id': 'renderProgramPage',
            '*path': 'errorpage'
        },

        errorpage: function () {
            requirejs(['views/404', 'views/dashboard'], function (errorview, DashboardView) {
                if ($('nav').length != 1) {
                    var authlogin = new AuthloginModel;
                    new DashboardView({model: authlogin});
                }
                new errorview;
            });
        },
        renderLoginPage: function () {
            requirejs(['models/auth', 'views/login'], function (AuthModel, LoginView) {
                var auth = new AuthModel;
                new LoginView({model: auth});
            });

        },
        renderDashBoard: function () {
            requirejs([
                'collections/reports',
                'views/reports',
                'views/dashboard',
                '../../javascript/main',
            ], function (ReportsCollection, ReportsView, DashboardView, MainJS) {

                var authlogin = new AuthloginModel;
                new DashboardView({model: authlogin});
                var reports = new ReportsCollection;
                reports.fetch({wait: true}).then(function () {
                    new ReportsView({collection: reports});
                });
            });

        },
        renderReportDetails: function (page) {

            requirejs([
                'models/reportdetails',
                'views/reportdetails',
                'views/dashboard'

            ], function (ReportDetailsModel, ReportdetailsView, DashboardView) {
                var reportdetails = new ReportDetailsModel({id: page});
                reportdetails.fetch().then(function () {
                    if ($('nav').length != 1) {
                        var authlogin = new AuthloginModel;
                        new DashboardView({model: authlogin});
                    }
                    ;
                    new ReportdetailsView({model: reportdetails});
                });
            });
        },
        renderNewReportPage: function () {
            requirejs([
                'collections/newreports',
                'views/reports',
                'views/newreports',
                '../../javascript/main',
            ], function (ReportsCollection, ReportsView, DashboardView, MainJS) {

            })
        },
        renderMembersPage: function () {
            requirejs([
                "collections/members",
                "collections/invitations",
                "views/members",
                'views/dashboard'
            ], function (MembersCollection, InvitationsCollection, MembersView, DashboardView) {
                var members = new MembersCollection();
                members.fetch().then(function () {
                    var invitations = new InvitationsCollection();
                    invitations.fetch().then(function () {
                        if ($('nav').length != 1) {
                            var authlogin = new AuthloginModel;
                            new DashboardView({model: authlogin});
                        }

                        new MembersView({collection: members, collection2: invitations});
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        renderOrganizationPage: function () {

            requirejs([
                'models/organization',
                'models/orgMembers',
                'views/organization',
                'views/dashboard'
            ], function (OrgModel, OrgMembers, OrgView, DashboardView) {

                var organization = new OrgModel();
                var members = new OrgMembers();
                organization.fetch().then(function () {
                    if ($('nav').length != 1) {
                        var authlogin = new AuthloginModel;
                        new DashboardView({model: authlogin});
                    }
                    members.fetch().then(function () {
                        new OrgView({model: organization, model2: members});
                    })
                })
            });
        },
        renderProgramsPage: function(){
            requirejs([
                'collections/programs',
                'models/program',
                'views/programs',
                'views/program',
                'views/dashboard'
            ],function(ProgramsCollection,ProgramsModel,ProgramsView,ProgramView,DashboardView){

               var programscollection = new ProgramsCollection;
                programscollection.fetch().then(function(){
                    if ($('nav').length != 1) {
                        var authlogin = new AuthloginModel;
                        new DashboardView({model: authlogin});
                    }

                    new ProgramsView({collection: programscollection});
                });


            });
        }


    });

    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

**Model**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
],function(_,Backbone){

    var ReportDetailsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        urlRoot: '/app/report/',
        idAttribute: 'id'
    });

    return ReportDetailsModel;

});
```

**View**

```
define([
    'backbone',
    '../../javascript/magnify_pop_up',
    'text!templates/reportdetails.html',
    'text!templates/reportcomments.html'
], function (Backbone, Magnify, ReportDetailsTemplate, RepCommentsTemplate) {
    var ReportdetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#container-2',
        template: _.template(ReportDetailsTemplate),
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },
        events: {
            "click #reject": "reject",
            "click #resolve": "resolve",
            "click button.triage": "triage"
        },
        triage: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.model.toJSON());
/*            this.model.save({'status':1},{patch:true,success:function(model,response){
                console.log('saved');
            },error:function(model,response){
                console.log('error');
            }});*/
        },
        resolve: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.model.save({'status':2},{patch:true});
        },
        reject: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.model.save({'status':3},{patch:true});
        },
        render: function () {
            $('#container').html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            this.$el.html(_.template(RepCommentsTemplate)(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
    return ReportdetailsView;

});
```